# Ionic Angular Tab image-text overlap

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

My ionic icon and tabs are overlapping in ios, but not in the web version.

Web version:
[image]

IOS version:[image]

Here's the code for the tabs:

```css
.tabs{
    height: 9vh;
}
```

```html
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar class="tabs" slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
      <!-- <ion-icon name="map-outline"></ion-icon> -->
      <i class="fi-rr-world icons"></i>
      <ion-label>Map</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button (click)="newGroup()">
      <!-- <ion-icon name="add-outline"></ion-icon> -->
      <i class="fi-rr-add icons"></i>
      <ion-label>Create</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab2" (click)="calendar()">
      <!-- <ion-icon name="calendar-outline"></ion-icon> -->
      <i class="fi-rr-calendar icons"></i>
      <ion-label>Calendar</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab3" (click)="profile()">
      <!-- <ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon> -->
      <i class="fi-rr-user icons"></i>
      <ion-label>Profile</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

I tried increasing the height of the ion-tab div, but that didn't work. Any advice as to how to fix this issue?

Comment: Also, changing the font-size of the icons isn't making it better.

Comment: Are you getting same result with `ion-icon`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue with some more complex css